# Crash on fetching empty columns from database, how to prevent? Java

Tags: java, sql, database, crash

```
String sql = "select spelprojekt.sid, beteckning from spelprojekt join arbetar_i on spelprojekt.sid = arbetar_i.sid join anstalld on arbetar_i.aid = anstalld.aid join specialist on anstalld.aid = specialist.aid where specialist.aid = " + specialistID + "";
String print = "";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> specialist = databas.fetchRows(sql);         

for (int i = 0; i < specialist.size(); i++) {
    print += specialist.get(i).get("SID") + " - " +specialist.get(i).get("BETECKNING") + "\n";
}

taSpelProjekt.setText(print);
```

So I have this code, I am trying to fetch two columns from the database and print it out to a jTextArea in netbeans.

everything works fine until i fetch a column with no value. the client crashes instead of just showing nothing in the textarea.

The last variable in the SQL is "`specialistID`" which change depending on what value i choose in a combobox. Everything works fine as long as there is something saved with that ID in the database. but I want to prevent the crash if the database columns are empty.

I'm getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyPackage.VisaSpecialister.cbSpecialistItemStateChanged(VisaSpecialister.java:180)
    at MyPackage.VisaSpecialister.access$000(VisaSpecialister.java:18)
    at MyPackage.VisaSpecialister$1.itemStateChanged(VisaSpecialister.java:90)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(JComboBox.java:1223)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(JComboBox.java:1271)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1330)
    at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(AbstractListModel.java:118)
    at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:93)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:576)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(JComboBox.java:622)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicComboPopup.java:852)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$1.processMouseEvent(BasicComboPopup.java:501)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/yGZBFbtf

this is what i get

Comment: it shows a nullpointer in line 180. Which line of your code is line 180?

Comment: Please provide more context. Obviously there is an itemChangeHandler involved. Please provide its source code. What type is `databas`? [InfDB](http://degj.github.io/InfDB/oru/inf/InfDB.html)? Please iterate over `specialist` using an Iterator. And you should use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments, i managed to solve this by adding

```
if(specialist != null){
    the loop here
}
```

While the database was empty at some ID's it fetches null, and the for-loop crashed when that was the case.

Probably not the best solution but it works for now :)